# how to get bigquery sql result in Spark dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, google-bigquery

I am querying bigquery table in my dataproc code,

```
fetch_history_query = 'SELECT * FROM {} WHERE ({}) = ("{}")'.format(bq_table, Columns, filer_value)
print(fetch_history_query)
client = bigquery.Client()
result_history = client.query(fetch_history_query).result().to_dataframe()
print(len(result_history))
```

Above code create `result_history` as `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`.
How Can I get result in `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use big query connector with spark.

Refer to below documentations for examples and more details:

https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example

https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).